# Should I use int or UInt16?

Tags: c#

This may be somewhat trivial, but in C# do you prefer int or UInt16 when storing a network port in a variable? Framework classes use int when dealing with a network port although UInt16 actually represents the valid values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

signed (`int` / `short` etc, rather that `uint` / `ushort`) have the advantage of being CLS compliant, so that is recommended unless you have a good reason.

Re `int` vs `short` - in most cases it is more efficient to *compute* with `int` (or `uint`), since all the operators are optimised for this. If you are only storing and retrieving it then this isn't an issue, of course.

Comment: I believe that unsigned types are CLS compliant starting with 2.0.  Been a long time since I looked at this though so I could be wrong.

Comment: @JaredPar - oddly, `ushort` doesn't raise a warning, but `uint` does (using VS2008): "Warning 1 Argument type 'uint' is not CLS-compliant"

Comment: @JaredPar - also, MSDN "This API is not CLS-compliant. The CLS-compliant alternative is Int32." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint16.aspx (also says that for 4.0)

Comment: hmm, I thought that had changed.  I'd trust the compiler warning over MSDN though

Answer (score 0):

if you have 32 bit processor and you will use 16bit value (for memory economy) it will be aligned to 32bit. So I think it is not so important use 16bit uint instead of 32bit value.